# Buchberger's Algorithm Terminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I was reading about the Buchberger algorithm from Dummit and Foote recently and was stumped by an exercise which is supposed to show the algorithm terminates in finitely many steps (Exercise $16$ from Chapter $9$):

> Fix a monomial ordering on $F[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ and suppose
> $G=\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_m\}$ is a set of generators for the nonzero ideal
> $I$ of $F[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$. Show that if $S(g_i,g_j)\not\equiv 0\; \textrm{mod } G$ for some
> $1\leq i,j\leq m$, then $\langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m),LT(S(g_i,g_j))\rangle$
> is strictly larger than
> $\langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m)\rangle$.

What really needs to be shown is that $LT(S(g_i,g_j))\not\in \langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m)\rangle$.
I know that we can right $S(g_i,g_j)$ as some polynomial $\sum_{k=1}^m h_kg_k + R$ where the multidegree of each term $h_kg_k$ does not exceed that of $S(g_i,g_j)$ under the given monomial ordering and $R$ is a nonzero polynomial such that no nonzero term of $R$ is divisible by any term $LT(g_k), 1\leq k\leq m$. I tried using this to write out two different expressions for $LT(S(g_i,g_j))$ and find a contradiction, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

I suppose part of the reason I should even expect the exercise statement to be true is, if $\langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m),LT(S(g_i,g_j))\rangle = \langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m)\rangle$, then this stabilizing of the ideal under the addition of a new element *might* mean that $\langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m)\rangle$ itself generates $LT(I)$ (the ideal generated by all leading terms of polynomials in $I$), but this would make $\{g_1,g_2,\dots,g_m\}$ a Groebner basis for $I$ contradicting the fact that $S(g_i,g_j)\not\equiv 0\; \textrm{mod } G$ (since $S(g_i,g_j)\in I$ always). But this idea feels weak. I don't know if it is actually true that the two ideals of lead terms being equal would force $\langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),\dots,LT(g_m)\rangle=LT(I)$, or even if this was the case, why it would be so.

Any help with this problem would be appreciated.